# How do i do to list all users_id who likes my fan_page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-page

How do i do to list all users_id who likes my fan_page? is it possible?

Comment: its not possible. this was asked very often on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible; you can check if a specific user is a fan of the page via several means, but there's no way to retrieve a list